# Symfony 6.4 - CollectionType exception FormView

Tags: forms, collections, symfony6

I have an entity CampaignConfig with a collection of campaignItems entities witch form view is failed. Error message is:

"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock(): Argument #1 ($view) must be of type Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, App\Entity\CampaignItem give"

Method controller:

```
.../... 
        $form   = $this->createForm(CampaignConfigForm::class, $campaignConfig, $options);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
.../... 
        return $this->render('config/'. $type .'.html.twig', [
            'form'              => $form->createView(),
            'campaign'          => $campaign,
            'campaignConfig'    => $campaignConfig,
            'itemsIn'           => $itemsIn,
            'itemsOut'          => $itemsOut,
        ]);
```

Entities:

```
class CampaignConfig
{
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: CampaignItem::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], mappedBy: 'campaignConfig', fetch: 'EXTRA_LAZY', orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $campaignItems;

.../... 

class CampaignItem
{
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity:CampaignConfig::class, inversedBy: 'campaignItems')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?CampaignConfig $campaignConfig = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $type = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $entryIn = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $entryOut = null;

.../...
```

forms are

CampaignConfigForm:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
.../...
            ->add($builder->create('campaignItems' , CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type'    => CampaignItemConfigForm::class,
                'label'         => false,
                'allow_add'     => true,
                'allow_delete'  => true,
                'prototype'     => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                ])
            )
.../...
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'    => CampaignConfig::class,
            'type'          => null,
            'itemsIn'       => null,
            'itemsOut'      => null,
        ]);
    }
```

CampaignItemConfigForm:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('entryIn', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label'         => 'Entrée',
                'placeholder'   => 'Sélectionner',
                'attr'          => [
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('entryOut', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label'         => 'Sortie',
                'placeholder'   => 'Sélectionner',
                'attr'          => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
            ])
.../...
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_campaign_config_campaignItem';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'        => CampaignItem::class,
            'csrf_protection'   => true,
            'validation'        => true,
        ]);
    }
```

template is rending this collection like that:

```
<div id="campaignItems" class="rounded bg-light"
    data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.campaignItems.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"
    data-widget-campaignItems="{{ '<div class="campaignItem border"></div>'|e }}"
    data-widget-counter="{{ form.campaignItems|length }}">
    
    {% for item in campaignConfig.campaignItems %}
        {# {{dump(item)}} #}
        {{ form_widget(item) }}
        {{ form_errors(item) }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and collection template:

```
{% block app_campaign_config_campaignItem_widget %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }} class="row px-3 pt-2 pb-3">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                {{ form_row(form.entryIn) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    {{ form_row(form.entryOut) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-n1 me-n2">
                    <span class="text-danger pointer removeItem" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
                        data-bs-title="Supprimer"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i></span>
                </div>
                {{ form_row(form.required) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock app_campaign_config_campaignItem_widget %}
```

JS is ok I can add items, but when there are campaignConfig.campaignItems, twig loop give an exception that I can't understand. It's not the first time I build a form with collection, I search similare trouble like that but nothing can help me and I think have a good use of SF documentation.

Twig dump is giving entities, but collection item form is out of render

I specify that Campaign entity has a campaignConfigs collection witch has campaignItems Collection (I don't know if it's important)

Have you an idea? Dind I missed something?